# Internal CSS code not rendering on GitHub pages. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: html, css, github

Working on a markdown file and hoping design it appropriately, however when I implement the CSS code internally (doing it internally because that's what we're learning at the moment) it styles it correctly on the markdown preview but not when I push it up to GitHub. I'm looking to render my styles in the actual GitHub readme.md file

How it styles on markdown preview:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LucZk.png "Markdown Preview"

How it renders on GitHub:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJuGf.png "Github rendering"

I've tried many different ways of writing the CSS code to see it that would get it to render correctly on GitHub, but to no avail.

This is my css style sheet that's written inside the markdown file.

```css
<head>
    <style>
        ul.navList {background-color: rgb(245,222,179)}
        ul.navList {text-decoration-line: underline}
        section {background-color: rgb(245,222,179)}
        section {border: solid black}
        section {padding: 10px}
        nav {background-color: rgb(245,222,179)}
        h2:first-letter {color: blue}
    </style>
</head>
```

Expecting this to render correctly showing the styles I've given it in the code on GitHub just like in the markdown preview.

Comment: Can you please provide your complete html file?

Comment: Do you open the page over `https://github.com/username/reponame` or `https://username.github.io/reponame/`?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub disallows `<style>` tags in Markdown files, because it could modify the look of GitHub itself. In the preview, it's only changed for you. So GitHub doesn't escape or strip the `<style>` tag. But once you push it, everyone who visits the page would see the new style. That's why it's not allowed.

You can check for yourself. The rendering engine is open source: 
https://github.com/github/markup

Or check the [spec](https://github.github.com/gfm) for more information. 
It has a whole section about escaped HTML code: 
https://github.github.com/gfm/#disallowed-raw-html-extension-

---

I'd recommend using actual `.html` files in combination with [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) (and without markdown-to-html static site generator) instead of markdown.

That way you have full control over your HTML file and can apply styles to your liking.